# Is there a way to make passing by reference, and passing by value explicit in the function call?

Tags: c++, c, c++11, parameters, parameter-passing

If you were to look at this code,

```
int x = 0;
function(x);
std::cout << x << '\n';
```

you would not be able to verify through any means of syntax, that parameter x is being passed by reference or that it's being passed by value.  The only way you would know for sure, is if you looked at either the function declaration or function definition.

Here is a simple example of how I believe this could be a problem:

```
std::string Lowercase(std::string str); //<- this is hidden away in code; probably in a different file.

int main(){
    std::string str = "HELLO";
    Lowercase(str);
    std::cout << str << '\n'; //<- Bug! we expected to output "hello".  The problem is not very easy to spot, especially when a function name sounds as though it will change the passed in value.
}
```

In order to avoid having to jump between the function call and the function declaration (or in some cases, the documentation) in order to understand the function behavior, is there a way to explicitly document in the syntax of a function call that the parameter is *expected to change* (i.e. a reference parameter) or that a *copy* is being sent (i.e. pass by value)?

I realize that there is also the option of passing by const& which has the similar notion to passing by value, in that the variable passed in, will not have its value changed after the function call.

---

I'm sure there are all kinds of situations in the language that might add to the complexity of understanding how a parameter is being passed- 
but I'm curious, is there a way to combat this problem in the way I want to?

I've noticed that some people write two similar functions.  One of them takes a value parameter, the other one takes a pointer.  That allows calling a function like this:

```
Lowercase(str); //we assume the value will not change
Lowercase(&str); //we assume the value will change
```

But this solution has many other issues, and I would not like to lose the benefit of references. Plus, we are still making assumptions on the behavior.

Comment: Certain users will kill me, cut me in four and burn my corps in hot oil for this, but to achieve this: **use a pointer.**

Comment: (Oh wait, it's not that bad, actually. Even Google people do it.)

Comment: @H2CO3 I've also seen it done in Facebook's "folly" library.

Comment: Sure. Pointers aren't quite as evil as some people assert.

Comment: What Stroustrup has to say about this: "To keep a program readable, it is often best to avoid functions that modify their arguments. [...] Consequently, 'plain' reference arguments should be used only where the name of the function gives a strong hint that the reference argument is modified" [TC++PL, 4th edition, pp.191]

Comment: I want to point out that `std::endl` is inappropriately used in the above code example: the flush is superfluous (the stream will be flushed upon destruction of the global object anyway), highlightening the problem I pointed out in my answer below: if you don't know what happens, you will misuse the facility, independent on what you indicate in the call.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Point made. :)

Comment: If you don't know what a function does you shouldn't call it. If you're maintaining code and you come across a function call and you don't know what it does, RTFM. If there's no FM, your development process is broken.

Comment: Just for Lowercase methods, I suggest having a case-based convention. That is: Lowercase() in uppercase will be in place, while lowercase() in lowercase will return a copy. easy.

Answer (score 27):

Some people insist that the correct way to pass mutable object is to use a pointer. That is, you would pass

```
Lowercase(&str);
```

... and `Lowercase()` would, obviously, be implemented to take a pointer. That approach may suit your needs.

I want to mention, however, that this is **not** what I would do! Instead, the approach I favor is to use appropriate names instead. For example,

```
inplace_lowercase(str);
```

pretty much says what it is going to do. Clearly, `inplace_lowercase()` would actually be an algorithm and with a bit of magic could be reasonably be called as

```
inplace_lowercase(str.begin() + 1, str.end());
```

as well.

Here are a few reasons why I don't like passing arguments by pointer and/or why I don't believe in an explicit indication of how the argument is passed:

- Pointers can be null. A mandated reference parameters should, in my opinion, be a reference.
- Passing by pointer still doesn't indicate whether the argument may be modified are not as the argument may be a `T const*`.
- Having meaningful names makes it actually easier to understand what's going on in the first place.
- Calling something without consulting its documentation and/or knowing what the called function will do doesn't work anyway and indicating how things are passed is trying to cure symptoms of a deeper problem.

Comment: +1 for accept a pointer if the object might not exist; accept a reference if the the object MUST exist, and you plan to change it; accept a const reference if the object MUST exist and you do not plan to change it; accept a value if the argument is a value not an object (admittedly somewhat ambiguous).   [I know this does not address the original question hence a comment, not an answer.]

Comment: Wouldn't be even better to make it take three arguments `lowercase(from_start, from_end, to_start)`?
This way you get rid of "inplace_" prefix and make user explicitly say where output should go (while still having only one function to do "lowercasing").

Comment: @elmo: `inplace_lowercase()` would probably just forward to another algorithm, e.g., a `lowercase()` like the one you describe. An in-place version may be more convenient to use. In either case, my point was that there are better alternatives to interface design than indicating how parameters are passed.

Comment: if the function returns bool or void then it is obvious that it is modifying it, if it returns the replaced string, then you should probably not be modifying it anyway, so no need for the verbose name.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure I understand your requirements completely, but maybe this is something you can use:

```
template<typename T>
void foo( T ) { static_assert( sizeof(T)==0, "foo() requires a std::ref" ); }

void foo( std::reference_wrapper<int> t )
{
    // modify i here via t.get() or other means of std::reference_wrapper
}

int main()
{
    int i = 42;
    // foo( i ); // does not compile, static_assert fires
    foo( std::ref( i ) ); // explicit std::ref visible on the caller's side
}
```

Comment: Or you could write an own type similar to `reference_wrapper` but with an explicit/private ctor. (And an implicit one which contains the `static_assert`.)

Comment: [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7647714d80a38d80) of the alternative.

Comment: @DyP Nice alternative which avoids the need to provide overloads for the user!

Answer (score 3):

Many (most) IDE's help you with this problem by displaying the function/method prototype(s) once they figure out which function you are calling.

Answer (score 3):

This is C++: the lack of `in` and `out` parameters doesn't mean the language is deficient, it means you need to implement what other languages would do as a language feature as a library.

Create two `template` classes and functions.

`in_param<T>` is a wrapper around a `T const&`, whilie `io_param<T>` is a wrapper around a `T&` reference.  You construct them by calling helper functions `in` and `io`.

Inside, they behave like references (via overloading).

Outside, the caller must call `in` or `io` on the argument, marking it up at the call site.

`out` is trickier: inside the fumction, only assignment is legal.  Ideally we would not even construct it: an `emplace` method might help.

However, the caller needs some channel to know if the parameter was constructed or not.

What I would do is `out_param` only has `operator=`, and it assigns.  `out` wraps something into an `out_param`.  If you want delayed constructuon, use `optional` inside the out param, which gets close.  Maybe `out_param` also has `emplace`, which usually just assigns, but if the tyoe wrapped has `emplace` calls it instead?

```
template<typename T>
struct in_param : std::reference_wrapper<T const> {
  explicit in_param( T const& t ):std::reference_wrapper<T const>(t) {}
  in_param( in_param<T>&& o ):std::reference_wrapper<T const>(std::move(o)) {}
  void operator=( in_param<T> const& o ) = delete;
};
template<typename T>
struct io_param : std::reference_wrapper<T> {
  explicit io_param( T& t ):std::reference_wrapper<T>(t) {}
  io_param( io_param<T>&& o ):std::reference_wrapper<T>(std::move(o)) {}
};
template<typename T>
in_param< T > in( T const& t ) { return in_param<T>(t); }
template<typename T>
io_param< T > io( T& t ) { return io_param<T>(t); }

template<typename T>
struct out_param {
private:
  T& t;
public:
  out_param( T& t_ ):t(t_) {}
  out_param( out_param<T>&& o ):t(o.t) {}
  void operator=( out_param<T> const& o ) = delete;
  void operator=( out_param<T> && o ) = delete;
  void operator=( out_param<T> & o ) = delete;
  void operator=( out_param<T> && o ) = delete;
  template<typename U>
  out_param<T>& operator=( U&& u ) {
    t = std::forward<U>(u);
    return *this;
  }
  // to improve, test if `t` has an `emplace` method.  If it does not,
  // instead do t = T( std::forward<Us>(us)... ). (I'd use tag dispatching
  // to call one of two methods)
  template<typename... Us>
  void emplace( Us&&... us ) {
    t.emplace( std::forward<Us>(us)... );
  }
};
template<typename T>
out_param<T> out( T& t ) { return out_param<T>(t); }
```

or something like the above.

You now get syntax like:

```
void do_stuff( int x, in_param<expensive> y, io_param<something> z, out_param<double> d );

int main() {
  expensive a;
  something b;
  double d;
  do_stuff( 7, in(a), io(b), out(d) );
}
```

and failure to call `in`, `io` or `out` at the call site results in compile time errors.  Plus, `out_param` makes it quite difficult to accidentally read the state of the `out` variable within the function, producing some very nice documentation at the call site.

Comment: would like to use it in our embedded project, but it lacks std::  lib support, is it possible to replace std:: functions with any others?

Answer (score 0):

If you use MS VC++ then maybe it will be useful information about source-code annotation language (SAL)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh916383.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think it's something useless to notify (by language nonetheless [1]). The only needed question is : "Is my object is semantically modified ?", and so :

- When you read a prototype you know if a function could modify an object (non-const ref) or not (copy or const ref).
- When you use a function (even without reading [2] the prototype) if you have to be sure to not modify an object, use a const_cast.

[1] A static analyzer could do it for its purposes.
[2] If you miss, the compiler would warn you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

That is the *whole point* of pass-by-reference -- that syntactically don't need to do anything different from passing by value.