# Distiguish a function call that gets a reference to a function call that get a value

Tags: c++, c

This is a function call that gets a pointer:

```
func2(&my_var); // its clear that func2 might change my_var
```

This is a function call that gets a copy/reference

```
func1(my_var); // not clear what will func1 will be doing to my_var
```

Is there a way to add a symbol (such as '&' is added for the first case ),  so that value and reference can be distinguished?

If not, any suggestions on how to write it better so it would be clear to the reader?

Comment: You just can't(without looking at the declaration/definition) which is for the better. The best you can do is speculate. So this seems opinion based.

Comment: Your C example for `func3` works purely based on your naming convention. `my_var` could already be a pointer (or a pointer to a pointer). There's no certainty in C, either.

Comment: why do you need this? I am not questioning your motivation, but the answer depends on it. If you are looking for a way to write `func1(my_var)` in a way that it is explicit whether `my_var` can be changed or not, there are ways. If you are asking whehter you can see in existing code whether `my_var` is modified by looking at `func1(my_var)` alone, its a different story

Comment: to quickly identify from searching 'my_var' where it is changed

Comment: you cannot know for sure if `func2(&my_var);` modifies `my_var`. It potentially modifies it and the same is true for `func1(my_var)`

Comment: efficiency I guess, leaves fewer places to check for debug, reading

Comment: you should rephrase the question to make it more clear and focused. Both "appears ugly, any better way?" and " I will probably get fewer search results?" are border line offtopic.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800841/is-there-a-way-to-make-passing-by-reference-and-passing-by-value-explicit-in-th

Answer (score 2):

I can understand why you ask this question. `func1(my_var)` and `func2(my_var)` can have very different effect when they look the same. However, in practice I never found this to be an actual issue.

IDEs that can show you the signature of the called function aside, there are more ways to mitigate the uncertainty of whether `my_var` is modified:

- Read documentation of functions you are using.
- Try to avoid out-reference-parameters. See [C++ Core Guideline F.20](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#f20-for-out-output-values-prefer-return-values-to-output-parameters). The rationale for the guideline is just what you mention: "A return value is self-documenting .." [in contrast to out parameters].
- Use meaningful names. `func1` is a bad name. `modify_it(my_var)` can be expected to modify `my_var` (either that or it has a very bad name). `print(my_var)` can be expected to not modify `my_var`.
- If nothing else helps, being more verbose for the sake of being explicit is better than comments:

  ```
  const auto& my_immutable_var = my_var;
  func1(my_immutable_var);
  ```

I suppose there are more ways to prevent confusion about whether `func1(my_var)` modifies `my_var` (limiting the scope of variables to the most narrow possible comes to my mind), but in general you are right, without looking at the function declaration there is no way to tell if `func1(my_var)` modifies `my_var`.